# Convert liste of vector3 to Json

Tags: json, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get all my lines render positions and add it to a list of vector3 then covert it to Json, so I can save it in the firebase. I'm using `JsonUtility`, but the problem is my jsondata is always empty even the list of vecor3 is not.

This is my code then I'm using :

```
 public class Path : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [SerializeField] private List<Transform> checkpoints = new List<Transform>();
     private LineRenderer linerenderer;
     public Material TheLineMateriel;

    public static bool _ispressed = false;
     private string DATA_URL = "https://kataraproject-a233a.firebaseio.com/";
     private DatabaseReference reference;

     public string hello = "khraaa" ;



     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(DATA_URL);
         reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

         GameObject lineObject = new GameObject();
         this.linerenderer = lineObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
         this.linerenderer.startWidth = 0.05f;
         this.linerenderer.endWidth = 0.05f;
         this.linerenderer.positionCount = checkpoints.Count;
         this.linerenderer.material = TheLineMateriel;
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         this.DrawLine();

     }

     private void DrawLine()
     {

         Vector3[] checkpointsArray = new Vector3[this.checkpoints.Count];
         for (int i = 0; i < this.checkpoints.Count; i++) {
             Vector3 checkpointPos = this.checkpoints[i].position;
             checkpointsArray[i] = new Vector3(checkpointPos.x, checkpointPos.y, 0f);
         }
          Vector3[] newPos = new Vector3[linerenderer.positionCount];
         this.linerenderer.SetPositions(checkpointsArray);

         linerenderer.GetPositions(newPos);


         //for (int i = 0; i < linerenderer.positionCount ; i++)
         //{

         //    newPos[i] = i;
         //}

         if ( _ispressed == true)
         {
             string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(checkpointsArray);

             //reference.Child("Position"  + Random.Range(0,1000000)).SetRawJsonValueAsync(jsonData);
             Debug.Log(jsonData);
             _ispressed = false;
         }
     }


    public void Save ()
     {
         _ispressed = true;
     }
 }
```

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple class to handle serialization of Unity types like such :

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializedVector3
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;

    public SerializedVector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public SerializedVector3(Vector3 vector3)
    {
        x = vector3.x;
        y = vector3.y;
        z = vector3.z;
    }
}

public static class Vector3Extensions
{
    public static Vector3 ToVector3(this SerializedVector3 serializedVector3)
    {
        return new Vector3(serializedVector3.x, serializedVector3.y, serializedVector3.z);
    }

    public static SerializedVector3 FromVector3(this Vector3 vector3)
    {
        return new SerializedVector3(vector3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of extension methods I would rather directly use implicit operators so you can use both types exchangeably. Also this still doesn't solve the (de)serialiazation of arrays in Unity.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in a project where I instantiate/save things to json. You just convert before/after serialization. Doesn't matter if it is an array or not if you do it like that. At least that's why I'm doing and it's solving my problem

Comment: I just create a class name Player 
[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public Vector3[] Position;

}
then i use it hear 
Player playerInstance = new Player();
            playerInstance.Position = newPos;
            string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerInstance);

            reference.Child("Position" + Random.Range(0, 1000000)).SetRawJsonValueAsync(jsonData);

Comment: @derHugo Implicit operators was a great idea and incredibly easy to implement on top of this solution.